# Module installation via web browser

Tags: 7, installation

I've a question regarding the installation of modules via the web browser. At the moment, I can easily upload both themes and modules to my Drupal site via sftp, but when I attempt to do the same using the module 'Update Manager' (i.e., through the web server itself, to avoid the hassle of adding the theme/module manually) I get an error that reads "Your server does not support installing modules and themes from this interface..." How does one enable the fix? I've read through some documentation regarding module installation but the comments seem contradictory, with some users suggesting a chown prompt and others saying such a solution is a breach of site security and thus to be avoided. Is there any consensus on what to do in this situation? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `php5-ftp` package and reload your webserver to load this extension.

Answer (score 0):

For installing module has many way:

- Install by browser: in module page in drupal installing ftp by ftp url. This link is module page in drupal
- Install by drush with drush en module_name
- Install with ftp. With ftp software upload module files in sites/all/modules and go to module page in drupal and install this.